# How to calculate difference in only one variable without including others from the dataset?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to calculate the change in life expectancy over the years for each country in the gapminder dataset. I am using the `lag` function to calculate this difference for each country with the data set.

i.e:

```
v <- 1:10
print(v)
v-v
v-lag(v)
```

When I try implementing this to the gapminder dataset, I end up calculating the difference in life expectancy between two different countries, which is not what I want to find. The code calculates the difference between the life expectancy of country B's earliest year and country A's earliest year in error.

my code:

```
library(gapminder)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

gm <- gapminder

explife <- gm %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(inc = lifeExp - lag(lifeExp)) %>%
  arrange(desc(inc)) %>%
  select(country, year, lifeExp, inc)

print(explife)
```

I also tried grouping by year as well, but all the values are NA.

```
library(gapminder)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

gm <- gapminder

explife <- gm %>%
  group_by(country, year) %>%
  mutate(inc = lifeExp - lag(lifeExp)) %>%
  arrange(desc(inc)) %>%
  select(country, year, lifeExp, inc)

print(explife)
```

Comment: There are multiple lag functions. (You probably are getting the dplyr one. ) You need to ensure that the one being used is from the package from which you can use it’s results be the rest of your code segment. You should include `library` calls and code to create ‘gm'

Comment: my apologies for the confusion, I've edited my code now

Comment: When running your code (after the edit)  I do get numeric  values for the `inc` variable at least for the first 10 of the 1704 entries that get printed. Can you explain why you consider them incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

The key lines of your code do seem to give the expected results, with all countries receiving `NAs` in their earliest years:

```r
library(dplyr)

gapminder::gapminder |> 
  group_by(country) |> 
  mutate(inc = lifeExp - lag(lifeExp)) |> 
  filter(is.na(inc))
#> # A tibble: 142 × 7
#> # Groups:   country [142]
#>    country     continent  year lifeExp      pop gdpPercap   inc
#>    <fct>       <fct>     <int>   <dbl>    <int>     <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 Afghanistan Asia       1952    28.8  8425333      779.    NA
#>  2 Albania     Europe     1952    55.2  1282697     1601.    NA
#>  3 Algeria     Africa     1952    43.1  9279525     2449.    NA
#>  4 Angola      Africa     1952    30.0  4232095     3521.    NA
#>  5 Argentina   Americas   1952    62.5 17876956     5911.    NA
#>  6 Australia   Oceania    1952    69.1  8691212    10040.    NA
#>  7 Austria     Europe     1952    66.8  6927772     6137.    NA
#>  8 Bahrain     Asia       1952    50.9   120447     9867.    NA
#>  9 Bangladesh  Asia       1952    37.5 46886859      684.    NA
#> 10 Belgium     Europe     1952    68    8730405     8343.    NA
#> # … with 132 more rows
```

Comment: my apologies for the confusion, I've edited my code now